# import fixed width file using mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I recently started working on SQL and I have a fixed width text file which has contents like this:

```
1220000937388930

Q2334GH467829749

567892390DFG2333

...

...

...
```

I want to import these into a MySQL data base and create columns using each entry in the FWF file. Say the columns would look like:

```
C1    C2      C3

12200 0093738 8930

Q2334 GH46782 9749
```

Could anyone help me how to achieve this?

Comment: Is length is fix for each column?

Answer (score 0):

First of all  create  a table name `all_data` with one column e.g. `data' and load the above data into this table. After that create a new table name`data_split`with 3 column e.g.`a`,`b`,`c`. Then load data into table like below.

```
insert into data_split(a,b,c) select substr(data,1,5),substr(data,6,8),substr(data,12,4) from data;
```

Comment: Could you please check the answer I'd posted and tell me if that is correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/'
INTO TABLE abc
(@row)
SET C1= TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,1,5)),
    c2= TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,6,12)),
    C3= TRIM(SUBSTR(@row,13,16))
;
```